# Get the middle value from a column according to a criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I need to get the value from col A and B in the middle of C when C = 1. If the amount of C = 1 is even, I want the first one from the middle

For example, this one is for an **odd amount** of C = 1

```
A B C
w y 0
c v 0
t o 1
e p 1
t b 1
u e 0
q p 0
```

The row in the middle when C = 1 is

```
A B C  
e p 1
```

Therefore, it should return

**df_return**

```
A B C
e p 1
```

When we have an **even amount** of C = 1:

**df_return**

```
A B C
w y 0
c v 0
t o 1
e p 1
t b 1
u e 1
r e 1
u f 1
q p 0
```

The ones in the middle when C = 1 are

```
A B C
t b 1
u e 1
```

However, I want only 1 of them, and it should be the first one. So
**df_return**

```
A B C
t b 1
```

How can I do it?

One thing you should know is that A and B are ordered

Answer (score 2):

Focus on the relevant part, discarding rows holding zeros:

```
df = df[df.C == 1]
```

Now it's simple. Just find the midpoint, based on length or `.shape`.

```
if len(df) > 0:
    mid = (len(df) - 1) // 2
    return df.iloc[mid, :]
```